# Syntax error with LAG function and WITH clause

Tags: sql-server, syntax, syntax-error, with-statement

I'm currently working with SQL server 2022,my database has a compatibility level of 160, but when I try to execute this statement:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        Id,
        LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS previous_id,
        Date,
        LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS previous_date
    FROM 
        dbo.Bellabeat_daily 
)
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Line 6 correspond to the FROM command.

I checked for misspellings in the columns and the table's name, but everything is correct. I appreciate any advise about what I've missed here.

Comment: You have no statement after your CTE declaration. You need to do *something* with the CTE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct syntax :

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT Id,
  LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS previous_id,
  Date,
  LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS previous_date
  FROM dbo.Bellabeat_daily 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Why the CTE at all if you're just going to `SELECT *` from it?

Comment: I didn't show my full querry, because I didn't know how to ask. However, I need the WITH clause to reference some aliases on another query.

This is the full query:

WITH CTE AS(
SELECT Id,
LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS previous_id,
Date,
LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS previous_date
FROM dbo.Bellabeat_daily )
SELECT Id,
 previous_id,
 Date, 
 previous_date,
 CASE
  WHEN Date IS NOT NULL THEN Date
  WHEN Date IS NULL AND (previous_date IS NULL) THEN NULL
  ELSE DATEADD(day, 1, previous_date)
 END AS ResultingDate
FROM CTE
WHERE Id = previous_id

Comment: There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77309495/edit) feature, @AlvaroC . Though the query you have posted is valid syntax.